# Проверка типов при обобщениях и установка разрешенных значений

Tags: c#, типы

Есть класс, который использует обобщение типов:

```
class DInit <T>
```

**Вопросы:** возможно ли задать типы, которые можно использовать при обобщении? Каким образом можно проверить типы внутри класса и вызвать нужный конструктор?

Comment: [where](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint)

Comment: Не смог разобраться. Дело в том, что в документации был пример (я его немного упростил): `class Dictionary<TKey>
        where TKey : IComparable, IEnumerable
    {
        public void Add(TKey key)
        {
        }
    }`.
Но при попытке инициализации класса (`Dictionary<IEnumerable> D = new Dictionary<IEnumerable>();`) появляется ошибка о том, что нет преобразования неявной ссылки. Каким образом это выполнить?

Comment: Условия where должны выполняться _все_. Это означает, что ваш `TKey` должен реализовывать как `IEnumerable`, так и `IComparable`. А `IEnumerable` реализует, понятно, только `IEnumerable`.

Comment: С этим все ясно, благодарю. Однако как реализовать, скажем, возможность использования только одного класса или интерфейса из нескольких доступных? Например: пользователю дана возможность использовать IComparable и IEnumerable, но требуется выбрать что-то одно.